# Mvc CheckBoxListFor named argument specifications error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

Im using Mvc CheckBoxListFor extension. Argument specification seems quite right to me as it's shown on the demos but it still gives me named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified error. And i also want to specify id attribute.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.Categories.PostedCategories.CategoryIds,
   model => model.Categories.AvailableCategories,
   entity => entity.CategoryId,
   entity => entity.Name,
   model => model.Categories.SelectedCategories,
   position: Position.Horizontal,
   x => new { @class = "actcheckbox" }) // here is the line that occurs that error.
   @Html.ValidationMessage("catSelectionError")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you have a named argument which is followed by a fixed argument - `position: Position.Horizontal`.  It would seem you need to do the following:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.Categories.PostedCategories.CategoryIds,
   model => model.Categories.AvailableCategories,
   entity => entity.CategoryId,
   entity => entity.Name,
   model => model.Categories.SelectedCategories,
   Position.Horizontal,  // NB: No argument name
   x => new { @class = "actcheckbox", id = "myid" })  // Add id here
```

Comment: thanks it worked as you suggest. how about giving different ids to each checkboxlist?